# Deploy a k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have deployed a k8s cluster using "kubeadm init" successfully before. I re-install the k8s when meet a problem. Now I re-deploy the k8s cluster failed!

linux os

```
uname -a
Linux kube-master 4.15.0-33-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 15 16:00:05 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

k8s env

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.2", GitCommit:"bb9ffb1654d4a729bb4cec18ff088eacc153c239", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-07T23:17:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

kubeadm version
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.2", GitCommit:"bb9ffb1654d4a729bb4cec18ff088eacc153c239", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-07T23:14:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

My deploy command:

```
sudo kubeadm -v 10 init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.0.100 --kubernetes-version v1.11.2

[init] this might take a minute or longer if the control plane images have to be pulled
I0828 17:12:47.780302   28675 round_trippers.go:386] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.11.2 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/bb9ffb1" 'https://192.168.0.100:6443/healthz?timeout=32s'
I0828 17:12:47.780492   28675 round_trippers.go:405] GET https://192.168.0.100:6443/healthz?timeout=32s  in 0 milliseconds
I0828 17:12:47.780500   28675 round_trippers.go:411] Response Headers:
I0828 17:12:48.280824   28675 round_trippers.go:386] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.11.2 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/bb9ffb1" 'https://192.168.0.100:6443/healthz?timeout=32s'
I0828 17:12:48.281238   28675 round_trippers.go:405] GET https://192.168.0.100:6443/healthz?timeout=32s  in 0 milliseconds
I0828 17:12:48.281283   28675 round_trippers.go:411] Response Headers:
I0828 17:12:48.780836   28675 round_trippers.go:386] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.11.2 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/bb9ffb1" 'https://192.168.0.100:6443/healthz?timeout=32s'
I0828 17:12:48.781171   28675 round_trippers.go:405] GET https://192.168.0.100:6443/healthz?timeout=32s  in 0 milliseconds
I0828 17:12:48.781199   28675 round_trippers.go:411] Response Headers:
I0828 17:12:49.281440   28675 round_trippers.go:386] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.11.2 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/bb9ffb1" 'https://192.168.0.100:6443/healthz?timeout=32s'
```

Who can help me?

Comment: did you try to backup the /etc/kubernetes/ folder and remove the whole content. It will be clean up add of configuraiton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `kubeadm init` you should copy *admin.conf* file into the home directory of the user who will use the `kubectl` command and set the config path into the `KUBECONFIG` system variable:

```
sudo cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf
```

It is a configuration file from where the `kubectl` reads details required to make a connection into your K8s cluster.